# update UI of view controller from another class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading

I have a `ViewController` with a progressView, label and button. A task runs in background in `task.swift` when user clicks on the button on `ViewController`. I want to update the label and progressView in `ViewController` based on progress of tasks in `task.swift`.

Comment: 1) You could keep a reference to the `ViewController` somewhere where the task has access to it. 2) You could use something like an `NSNotification` to send an update to an observer. 3) You could keep a common state object that is passed between tasks/view controllers. Other possibilities, too. Include your code and what you've tried and you might be able to get a better answer for your problem.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I had no idea how to approach. Thanks for your response it gave me an idea. I'm going to use struct with static variables to track the progress.

Comment: I'm not sure how a struct with static variables would solve this.

Comment: yeah you are right, didn't think it through.

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift Communication Patterns

You have multiple ways of setting up communication between 2 classes in Swift:

1. Method call / return
2. Delegate pattern
3. Closure
4. Notification pattern
5. Publishers subscribers

#### Respect MVC (Model - View - Controller)

Because you want your model (here `Task`) to not be aware about the ViewController in order to respect MVC, you cannot apply just a simple method call through the reference.

#### Pick the right one

However all the others ways are totally valid. Because it seems to be a 1 to 1 relationship between ViewController and Task, the most simple solutions would be to use a delegate or a closure. If your classes relationship would have been a one to many, you could have picked notification. Publishers would be for reactive programming and if you like Combine.